# Android phone fails to install apk copied on the phone

Tags: android, apk

I am building Android Application .apk file using Android Studio 4.0.
I am able to install and test the application on my Mi phones.
I am also able to copy the APK file on SD card and able to tap and install the apk and it works perfectly.

But when I copy same apk to my Samsung phone and if I try to install, it fails to install with no specific error message. If I install same app with "$ adb install -t test.apk" then it works.

I have developer option and also "Install application from unknown source" enabled in both the phones.

Do I need to perform any configuration in the Android Studio to make the app installable on any phone?

I did try with adding `android:testonly="false"` but it did not work.

Comment: Is it the first time you try installing it on that device? I found sometimes that after uninstalling an app, if the device has multiple users (guest user for example), the app is kept installed for other users, even though it doesn't appear visible in your app drawer. To uninstall it you would need to go to Settings > Apps and select "Uninstall for all users"

Comment: @JosebaS. Device is not having multiple user only one single user. Also it is getting installed when I install with "$ adb install -t debug.apk" but not when I copy the apk file on the phone and then tap on it to install. I have all the necessary options enabled in the phone settings.

Comment: But did you look if it appears under Settings > Apps after uninstalling it? Installing it from the adb has more elevated permissions than from the local .apk

Comment: @JosebaS. As app is not getting installed when I tap on the apk file I am not able to see it under the Settings > Apps. I am confused how it can work on one phone and fail on other. Do I need to add some sort of settings the APK to make it run on the all the phone?